# What's the difference between channel and mutex in Golang?

Tags: multithreading, go, channel

I have heard that `channel` is better than `sycn.Mutex.Lock()` when your program is of high concurrency. But why channel is more efficient? In my opinion, to implement a safe buffer pool(I think channel can be consider as a buffer pool), you must use lock.

And if `channel` is more efficient, why there is `sycn.Mutex`? Because I can write the code below to mock `sync.Mutex`.

```golang
type seme struct {
    lock chan int
    locked bool
}


func (l *seme)Lock() {
// state 0 for initial, 1 for locked, 2 for free.
    if atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&l.state, 0, 1) {
        l.lock = make(chan int, 1)
    }
    l.lock <- 0
    l.state = 1
}

func (l *seme)UnLock() {
    if !atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&l.state, 1, 2)  {
        panic("UnLock a free Lock")
    }
    l.state = 2
    <- l.lock
}
```

If `channel` is better everywhere than `mutex`, why should I use `mutex`? That is, when should I use `mutex` but not `channel`? Can someone give me an example?

Comment: There is no advantage to using a channel for the lock and unlock operations in the question. The problem with using a channel is that it's more difficult to get the code correct.  The first version and second versions of the question have data races.

Comment: If a correct lock implementation using channels had better performance than the sync.Mutex implementation,  then the Go team would rewrite sync.Mutex to use channels.

Comment: @CeriseLimón why does the code have data races? Could you please give me an example?

Comment: I have run a benchmark, and find that `sync.Mutex` seems more efficient...

Comment: Data race: The Lock function ensures that no more than one goroutine can create the channel, but the function does not guarantee that write to `l.lock` happens before the the read of `l.lock`.

Comment: "I have heart that channel is better than sycn.Mutex.Lock() when your program is of high concurrency." Stop listening to such people. There never is a single "better". Sometimes A is more suitable, sometimes B. Simple and general answers are wrong answers.

Answer (score 8):

A channel is fundamentally different from a mutex.

A proper answer with enough details would be too long, so let's just cover the main highlights, specifically in terms of Go channels:

- A Go channel provides *typed data transfer* between concurrent routines (goroutines).
- A `sync.Mutex` provides *mutual exclusion to shared memory* between concurrent routines (goroutines).

Data transfer represents *copying a value* of some type T.  Goroutine A puts a value into the channel:

```
var v T  // v is a value of type T
...
ch <- v  // put v's value into the channel
```

When and whether the attempt to put `v` *into* the channel *blocks*, and what you can do about this if you like, gets a bit complicated, but if the channel is *buffered*, then at least *some* values can go into it right away without any blocking, so that the sending goroutine can continue.  If the channel is *unbuffered*, the sender blocks until some receiver goroutine is actively waiting for a value.  (Sometimes this is desirable, and sometimes it isn't.)

Meanwhile, goroutine B takes a value out of the channel:

```
var w T  // w is also a value of type T
...
w <- ch
```

or just:

```
w :=<- ch
```

Again, when and whether this blocks, what you can do, when you should do something, etc., can get complicated; but in the simple case, this waits for there to be a value available—for some goroutine to do the `ch <- v`, or to have already done it if the channel is buffered—and then it copies into variable `w` the value that was put into the channel.  The variable `v` may have changed, or even been totally destroyed by this point.  The *value* was safely stored in the channel, and has now been removed from the channel and put into the variable `w`.

Go channels have some additional features, such as the ability to *close* a channel, which prevents further writes on it and delivers "end of data" notices to read operations.  This is test-able with single value reads (`w, ok <- ch`) and is implicitly tested in a `for w := range ch` loop.

A `sync.Mutex` instance, by contrast, simply lets you call `Lock` and `Unlock`.  It does not hold any queued-up values (as a buffered channel would), nor even have a type (other than `sync.Mutex` itself) that keeps you from accidentally sending a `float` to something expecting `string` or whatever.  The existence of this lock lets two or more goroutines use *shared memory regions* to get something done.

The *runtime implementation* of a channel is very likely to need some kind of mutex.  This does not have to be `sync.Mutex` itself: anything that provides enough mutual exclusion will suffice.  In [the Go channel implementation you are probably using](https://golang.org/src/runtime/chan.go), it is not a `sync.Mutex` but rather a specialized [runtime mutex](https://golang.org/src/runtime/runtime2.go#L161).  (Note that this link goes to a specific line and the line may get out of date over time.)  Because some channel code is directly generated by the compiler itself, the runtime routines here should not be assumed to be in use: your compiler may be different.  Studying this particular implementation might, however, enlighten you quite a bit about what you can do with channels.

Mutexes are generally much *simpler* than channels.  To see an example, compare the amount of code in the above channel implementation—which doesn't include the compiler's inline insertions—to this particular Go implementation's [`sync.Mutex` source code](https://golang.org/src/sync/mutex.go).

Comment: Though not directly answered, it can be inferred that all `Mutex`'s can be replaced by channels with buffer size one technically, which is consistent with OP's conclusion, right? And their performance would be similar since neither of them would be eating up all CPU time by looping to check its status?

Comment: @MeowCat2012: if you mean that you can replace a mutex `m` with a channel `ch` (of some arbitrary type, but let's pick type `struct{}`), with `m.Lock()` being represented as `ch <- struct{}{}` and `m.Unlock()` being represented as `<-ch` and the channel depth being set to 1: that would seem to be the case. The performance of the channel is likely to be poorer, though: the mutex remains fundamentally simpler = fewer synchronized instructions.

Comment: Thanks. For situations where locks can be timed out and given up, a channel have to be used in place.

Comment: @MeowCat2012: yes, that's one of the extra features of a channel that makes it heavier-weight than a simple mutex. If the extra features are needed, one can build all the same functionality *with* mutex-plus-condition-variable-plus-other-data-structures ... or one can just use channels. :-)

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to communicate in concurrent programs in Golang.

1. sync package: Communicate by sharing memory.
2. Channels: Share memory by communicating.

Go recommends

> Do not communicate by sharing memory. Instead, share memory by
>   communicating.

[What operations are atomic? What about mutexes?](https://golang.org/doc/faq) addresses this question